# How to run tasks sequentially in a loop in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: python, airflow

Say I have this snippet of an example DAG:

```
variables = ['first', 'second', 'third']

def run_dag_task(variable):
  task = dag_task(variable)
  return task

for variable in variables:
  run_dag_task(variable)
```

This code would run the three tasks for the three variables in parallel. Now, say I want the first task to finish before commencing the second task, and to finish the second task before commencing the third task. How would I go about doing this with a loop? Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

```
variables = ['first', 'second', 'third']

def run_dag_task(variable):
  task = dag_task(variable)
  return task
task_arr=[]
task_arr.append(run_dag_task(variable[0]))

for variable in variables[1:]:
  task=run_dag_task(variable)
  task_arr[-1]>>task
  task_arr.append(task)
```

This should do what you need. Add tasks on to an array and setup the relationship

Comment: This option is the best, suitable in what Stijnav is asking, Also I faced the same problem to avoid DRY (do not repeat yourself)
What is neccesary to mention is which is what you add to your task sequences:
{code:python}
( init >> do_somethin >> task_arr[0] >> end)
{code}

Answer (score 4):

In Airflow, you can define order between tasks using `>>`. For example:

```py
task1 >> task2
```

Which would run `task1` first, wait for it to complete, and only then run `task2`. This also allows passing a list:

```py
task1 >> [task2, task3]
```

Will would run `task1` first, again wait for it to complete, and then run tasks `task2` and `task3`.

Your example could be written as:

```py
start = 'first'
variables = ['second', 'third']

def run_dag_task(variable):
  task = dag_task(variable)
  return task

start_task = run_dag_task(start)
next_tasks = [run_dag_task(var) for var in variables]
start_task >> next_tasks
```

Comment: Maybe I should've specified that I want all tasks to run sequentially, so 'third' should only run once 'second' is completed. In your example I believe 'second' and 'third' would run in parallel, but after 'first' is finished. I am aware of the >> operator to run tasks sequentially outside of a loop, but I am curious if I can run everything sequentially within a loop.

Comment: You need some way to reference the previous/next task in a for loop. You could add all your tasks to a list and call `chain()`:

```python
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

tasks = [..., ..., ...]
chain(*tasks)
```

Which sets dependencies sequentially between all tasks in a list. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that could work. If I were to append each task at the end of the loop to a list and then use chain to run them sequentially, that should give me the desired outcome. I will definitely try this. Thanks!

Comment: Update: the chain() function does indeed do the job. By appending my tasks in a loop to a list and then using chain() on the list, the tasks within the list are run sequentially!