# Run DAG tasks in loop

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to airflow and have a scenario to pull off. I need to pull a list from xcom and then loop over a set of tasks. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002086/how-to-run-tasks-sequentially-in-a-loop-in-an-airflow-dag) answer and it works well. I still am not able to get the list from xcom, outside a task so i can loop.

```
variables = ['first', 'second', 'third']
def run_dag_task(variable):
    task = dag_task(variable)
    return task
task_arr=[]
task_arr.append(run_dag_task(variable[0]))

for variable in variables[1:]:
    task=run_dag_task(variable)
    task_arr[-1]>>task
    task_arr.append(task)
```

I also found a few answers which suggested to use functions as get_task_instance or TaskInstance but since i'm planning to run this in an automated environment, it won't be feasible for me to depend on this, as if I execute it first time today, it will never work.
The main challange I am facing is I have to get the xcom value and outside a task and then loop over a set of tasks. something like this

```
def run_dag_task(variable):
    task = dag_task(variable)
    return task
task_arr=[]
task_arr.append(run_dag_task(variable[0]))
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
variables = xcom_pull(key="some_list")
for variable in variables[1:]:
   task=run_dag_task(variable)
   task_arr[-1]>>task
   task_arr.append(task)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
start >> task_arr >> end
```

I need a solution where i can pull the `variables` from xcom, loop over set of tasks and then move on to the other tasks. Also i have a few tasks before I loop.
I'm open to any other options too, like may be looping and calling a external dag over and over to loop.